# Sorting 3D curves to logical groupings. Python ideal

Tags: python, maya

I'm really lost here and trying to come up with a method to sort different 3d curves that have no relation. Visually, any human could look at them and figure out (albeit slowly) what curves belong together as a group. Each group of curves here "flows" pretty clearly from one to the next.

In the below example, there are 5 groupings of curves. Each group flows. Some of these groups are far away from the others, and easy to create code to detect. Others are much closer to each other. Those are really tough to detect since there's a lot of overlap.

I've tried distance checks at the start and end of each curve, but that's not enough. Sometimes curves pass through other curves. So some understanding of the history of the curve flow seems to be important.

Are there existing methods out there to solve this sort of thing?

[image]

Comment: apart creating them properly grouped or making calculation by comparing first points, end points and maybe angle, im not sure if there is an easy solution when there is overlap

Comment: @DrWeeny Unfortunately, I think you're right. It's really been a struggle. I've added more samples to the original curves, but there are too many possibilities to calculate (at least for me). Thank you for the reply.